Connecting to MySQL in Qt6
I want to connect to MySQL in Qt6, but the connection is not working. My instructor said that you want to run a diesel car with gasoline and that you need to use a different library instead of QSqlDatabase.
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("barkod");
    db.setPort(3306);
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("password");
    if(db.open()){
        qDebug() << "Connected";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Disconnected";
    }

I can't find anyone on the internet who has done this using QSqlDatabase. What could be a different library for the solution? What did my instructor mean?

Your code is correct however did you build the Mysql driver? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html

I bet you can do better than just "my code is not working". Qt is usually quite verbose when something "doesn't work", and you should see at least some error messages like "QMYSQL driver not loaded" or "available drivers: xxx ...", or something about event loops, or some warnings about threads, depends how your real code looks like.

What did my instructor mean? I am not sure what he meant because what you are doing can work if you compiled and installed the database driver. Although using Code::Blocks as your IDE for Qt probably will make things more difficult than if you used Qt-Creator or Visual Studio Community + CMake.

QSqlDatabase has an lastError() function - you should use it.

QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSq1Database: available drivers: QSQLITE QMIMER QMARIADB QMYSQL QODBC QPSQL
Di sconnected
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
